# how to display my image from this api url? i trying to display img from api into tableview cell but i keep getting this error, is it my code wrong?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uitableview

[image]

Why do i keep getting this error? what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like your URL is not getting created, check what data you get from PostsDetail["cat_icon"] ?

Comment: it returns the image url that i stored.
 "Optional(https://api.jocom.com.my/images/category/579-1439460321.png
.......
"

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the cell class?

```
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTableViewCell")
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Kingfisher Libarary](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

```
imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://your_image_url.png")!)
```